# Using glass bottles in walls of buildings

Tags: recycling, reuse, building

I have seen pictures of homes and buildings in dry climates were they have used glass bottles in the walls with what looks like either concrete or mud.  Is this just for aesthetics?  Do they provide any structural and insulating properties?